# Expansion of Jacobi theta function at $p$-torsion

Tags: cv.complex-variables, elliptic-curves, theta-functions, theta-series

I am aware of the formula $$\Theta(z,q)=z\exp\left( -2\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}E_{2k}(q)\right)$$ for the Jacobi theta function at the origin $z=0$. The definition I am using for the theta function is $$\Theta(z,q)=(e^{z/2}-e^{-z/2})\prod_{m\geq 1} \frac{(1-e^zq^m)(1-e^{-z}q^m)}{(1-q^m)^2}.$$ Is there a similar formula for the expansion at a $p$-torsion point $z=\tfrac{2\pi ri}{p}$?

EDIT: It isn't hard to show that the $q^n$ coefficients in the expansion of $\ln \Theta(z,q)$ for $n>0$ can be expressed in terms of Eisenstein series. Thus, I am particularly interested in the modularity/level of the constant term $$\Theta(\tfrac{2\pi ri}{p},q)=(\zeta_p^{r/2}-\zeta_p^{-r/2})\prod_{m\geq 1} \frac{(1-\zeta_p^rq^m)(1-\zeta_p^{-r}q^m)}{(1-q^m)^2}.$$ I think something like Shimura's "On modular forms of half-integral weight" is relevant, but the statements don't seem to apply directly. I would like the level to be $p^2$ but perhaps according to Shimura, I should expect $4p^2$?

Comment: It is quite simple using the identity $-\partial_z^2 \ln\Theta(z) = \wp(z)$.

Comment: Correction: It is simple to express the answer in terms of $\Theta(\tfrac{2\pi ri}{p})$ and Eisenstein series. The former is expressible in terms of an $\eta$ ratio when $p=2,3,4,6$, but it is not clear to me that in general what are the modular properties of this value of the theta function.

Comment: I found a reference: https://ir.nctu.edu.tw/bitstream/11536/26403/1/000224115200011.pdf